# How can I identify recently expired passwords?

Tags: powershell, datetime, active-directory

I've been using a line of code along the lines of that below in order to calculate when users passwords are due to expire.

```
$Expiration = (([datetime]::FromFileTime((Get-ADUser –Identity 'MyTestUser' -Properties "msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed")."msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed"))-(Get-Date)).Days
```

The trouble with this is, as I run this each night, some passwords that have expired recently give the result as 0 although the it's actually a minus number that's rounded. My question is, can I get a more detailed answer so I can do  this accurately? I need to be able to compare the results in an if statement as I want to determine if the users password expires over a weekend etc... so that I can notify them.

I have everything else, just the query detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the code works the way you want you are restricting yourself by working based of `.Days`. The value is not rounded it is just reporting full days. [Timespan](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan(v=vs.110).aspx) objects have other properties as well.

Instead I would suggest working from `TotalHours` and add some logic that would work with negative values as well. Something like `$Expiration -gt -24 -and  $Expiration -lt 72`. That should represent expired in the last 24 hours or in the next 3 days.

Comment: Total Hours is exactly what I needed